# If x is y percent, what is the total (100%)?

Tags: arithmetic, estimation

If x is y percent, what is the total (100%)?

I will explain my question with an example scenario for better context of problem

Scenarios:

- Some person in 22 minutes, drove for 67 kilometers, then how much the person can drive in 1 Hr?
- Some person in 129 minutes, drove for 116 kilometers, then how much the person can drive in 1 Hr?

What is the correct way to formulate this estimation scenario, more accurately to find the answer

The question looks simple at first, like calculate per minute and then find out per 60 min. but it is incorrect in scenario where person has already driven more than 1 Hr or driven for very less time. Adding to it, different people may drive at different speed and the question is to find out that very speed.

Hence I restate the question as below for one of the question

`Question:- Some person in 22 minutes, drove for 67 kilometers, then how much the person can drive in 1 Hr?`

- if in 22 minutes is approx 37% of an Hour, person took 37% of a hour to drive 67 KM
- in in 60 minutes or 100% of an Hour, person will drive how much?

Hence I think this is estimating equivalent %age calculation of a variable (KM drove) with respect to another variable (time taken)

is this like Calculating or Estimating, equivalent percentage of change needed to a variable basis percentage change in other related variable

Comment: This technique is known as dimensional analysis. There's tons of resources out there to help walk you through it.

Comment: You neither need nor should be using percentages. You should follow the advice given by @William. Dimensional analysis may sound prohibitive but it is actually a very simple and intuitive way to do these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some questions to help you approach these kind of problems. Note it's the same pattern every time.

"Some person in 22 minutes, drove for 67 kilometers, then how much the person can drive in 1 Hr?"

- How far does this person drive in 1 minute?
- So, how far does this person drive in 60 minutes?

(There is no point in computing first that 22 minutes is approximately 37% of an hour, so the person drives 67 km in 37% of an hour, and then calculate the number of km in a full hour. That just complicates the calculation and results in exactly the same.)

"Some person in 129 minutes, drove for 116 kilometers, then how much the person can drive in 1 Hr?"

- How far does this person drive in 1 minute?
- So, how far does this person drive in 60 minutes?

"If $x$ is $y$ percent, what is the total?"

- How much is 1 percent?
- So, much is 100 percent?